# Qualcomm Atheros wifi connection issue on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, realtek

This has been asked a few times but I have tried probably every alternative available and still my wireless connection is **not persistent**.
I will add the necessary info below.

```
 -inspiron-15-3567:~$ uname -r 4.4.0-87-generic
```

Above is the kernel version
The output for lshw is below:

```
my13-inspiron-15-3567
description: Laptop
product: Inspiron 15-3567 (078B)
vendor: Dell Inc.
serial: JYR42F2
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=docking family=Inspiron sku=078B uid=44454C4C-5900-1052-8034-CAC05F314632
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: 05269N
   vendor: Dell Inc.
   physical id: 0
   version: A00
   serial: /JYR42F2/CNWSC0072J00ME/
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Dell Inc.
      physical id: 0
      version: 01.00.03
      date: 11/16/2016
      size: 64KiB
      capacity: 15MiB
      capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 3d
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 4GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: SODIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
         product: 4ATF51264HZ-2G3B1
         vendor: Synertek
         physical id: 0
         serial: 15337CE4
         slot: DIMM A
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: [empty]
         physical id: 1
         slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
 *-cache:0
      description: L1 cache
      physical id: 41
      slot: L1 Cache
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 128KiB
      capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
      configuration: level=1
 *-cache:1
      description: L2 cache
      physical id: 42
      slot: L2 Cache
      size: 512KiB
      capacity: 512KiB
      capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
      configuration: level=2
 *-cache:2
      description: L3 cache
      physical id: 43
      slot: L3 Cache
      size: 3MiB
      capacity: 3MiB
      capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
      configuration: level=3
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 44
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: U3E1
      size: 1131MHz
      capacity: 3100MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
      configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: Intel Corporation
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 02
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
         resources: irq:279 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
    *-generic:0
         description: Signal processing controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
         version: 02
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi pm cap_list
         configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
         resources: irq:16 memory:d1320000-d1327fff
    *-usb
         description: USB controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 21
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:124 memory:d1310000-d131ffff
       *-usbhost:0
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-87-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 0
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-3.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
       *-usbhost:1
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-87-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@1
            logical name: usb1
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:0
               description: Video
               product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
               vendor: CN0F08KG724876CHA71NA01
               physical id: 5
               bus info: usb@1:5
               version: 52.68
               serial: 200901010001
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:1
               description: Generic USB device
               product: USB2.0-CRW
               vendor: Generic
               physical id: 6
               bus info: usb@1:6
               version: 39.60
               serial: 20100201396000000
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:2
               description: Bluetooth wireless interface
               vendor: Atheros Communications, Inc.
               physical id: 8
               bus info: usb@1:8
               version: 0.01
               capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
               configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
    *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
         description: Signal processing controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
         version: 21
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:d1338000-d1338fff
    *-generic:2
         description: Signal processing controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 15
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
         version: 21
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
         resources: irq:16 memory:d1337000-d1337fff
    *-generic:3
         description: Signal processing controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 15.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
         version: 21
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
         resources: irq:17 memory:d1336000-d1336fff
    *-communication
         description: Communication controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 21
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
         resources: irq:280 memory:d1335000-d1335fff
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 17
         bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
         version: 21
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:277 memory:d1330000-d1331fff memory:d1334000-d13340ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:d1333000-d13337ff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: f1
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:122 memory:d1000000-d11fffff
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: Qualcomm Atheros
            vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            logical name: wlp1s0
            version: 31
            serial: r8:3b:ad:5a:2f:y3
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-87-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00377-1 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
            resources: irq:281 memory:d1000000-d11fffff
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
         version: f1
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:123 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:d1200000-d12fffff
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: enp2s0
            version: 07
            serial: a8:6b:ad:5a:1f:f3
            capacity: 100Mbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8101 driverversion=1.032.04-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
            resources: irq:278 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d1204000-d1204fff memory:d1200000-d1203fff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 21
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
    *-memory UNCLAIMED
         description: Memory controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 21
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:d132c000-d132ffff
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 21
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
         resources: irq:289 memory:d1328000-d132bfff memory:d1300000-d130ffff
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
         version: 21
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:d1332000-d13320ff ioport:f040(size=32)
 *-scsi:0
      physical id: 1
      logical name: scsi0
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: WDC WD10JPVX-75J
         vendor: Western Digital
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 1A02
         serial: WX21A177YJ3K
         size: 931GiB (1TB)
         capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
         configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=b5be0916-9791-44c0-acf8-0d846795df29 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
       *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
            description: Windows FAT volume
            vendor: MSDOS5.0
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
            version: FAT32
            serial: 8eb3-e018
            size: 495MiB
            capacity: 499MiB
            capabilities: boot fat initialized
            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=ESP name=EFI system partition
       *-volume:1
            description: Windows FAT volume
            vendor: MSDOS5.0
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            version: FAT32
            serial: 4417-97da
            size: 3048MiB
            capacity: 3071MiB
            capabilities: fat initialized
            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=OS name=Basic data partition
       *-volume:2
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 3
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
            logical name: /dev/sda3
            logical name: /
            version: 1.0
            serial: 8831913b-418c-400f-822c-8f711a6f0b3c
            size: 920GiB
            capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2017-02-21 16:47:13 filesystem=ext4 label=UBUNTU lastmountpoint=/ modified=2017-10-09 16:34:30 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2017-10-09 16:34:40 state=mounted
       *-volume:3
            description: Linux swap volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 4
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
            logical name: /dev/sda4
            version: 1
            serial: 35863012-3721-49ea-b59a-f6c7be3b2e35
            size: 7926MiB
            capacity: 7927MiB
            capabilities: nofs swap initialized
            configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 2
      logical name: scsi1
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVD+-RW GU90N
         vendor: HL-DT-ST
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/cdrw
         logical name: /dev/dvd
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: A1C1
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
*-battery
   product: DELL 991XP71
   vendor: LG
   physical id: 1
   version: 12/29/2016
   serial: D9D8
   slot: Sys. Battery Bay
   capacity: 41440mWh
   configuration: voltage=14.8V
```

Output of nmcli:

```
   inspiron-15-3567:~$ nmcli general
   STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
   connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

What further steps would help me debug the problem further and reach a solution?

**Update**
 I am adding the `dmesg` log below.

```
    [   15.522170] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: can't find device of ID00e0
    [   15.522172] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e0
    [   15.522178] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: can't find device of ID00e0
    [   15.522179] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e0
    [   15.522185] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: can't find device of ID00e0
    [   15.658109] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC3246: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
    [   15.658112] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
    [   15.658113] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
    [   15.658114] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
    [   15.658115] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
    [   15.658117] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
    [   15.658118] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1a
    [   15.658119] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
    [   15.914763] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
    [   15.914821] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
    [   15.914872] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
    [   15.914924] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
    [   15.914971] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
    [   15.915019] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
    [   15.935256] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
    [   16.236034] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
    [   16.236036] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
    [   16.855276] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
    [   16.855280] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
    [   16.855282] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
    [   16.855284] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
    [   16.952273] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
    [   17.252997] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
    [   17.284823] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
    [   17.548504] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input15
    [   17.710184] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0bda:5769)
    [   17.714351] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input16
    [   17.714393] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
    [   17.714394] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
    [   17.851613] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 (0x05020001, 0x003821ff sub 1028:1810) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
    [   17.851616] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
    [   17.852441] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
    [   17.852443] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
    [   17.852444] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
    [   17.852445] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
    [   17.912577] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F6.0001: Scanning PDT...
    [   17.915009] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F6.0001: Found F34 on page 0x00
    [   17.917435] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F6.0001: Found F01 on page 0x00
    [   17.919856] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F6.0001: Found F11 on page 0x00
    [   17.925380] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F6.0001: Found F54 on page 0x01
    [   17.927799] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F6.0001: Found F30 on page 0x01
    [   17.933318] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F6.0001: rmi_scan_pdt: Done with PDT scan.
    [   17.963521] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F6.0001: rmi_populate_f11: size in mm: 102 x 62
    [   17.976938] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F6.0001: firmware id: 2430125
    [   17.976985] input: DELL078B:00 06CB:78F6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-4/i2c-DELL078B:00/0018:06CB:78F6.0001/input/input17
            [   19.061025] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [   19.061026] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [   19.061027] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [   19.061028] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [   19.061029] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
    [   19.061030] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
    [   19.061031] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [   19.061032] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
    [   21.444301] Adding 8118268k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8118268k FS
    [   24.974996] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.704:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/ubuntu-core-launcher" pid=875 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   25.019862] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.744:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=872 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   25.019868] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.744:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=872 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   25.019870] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.744:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=872 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   25.019873] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.744:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=872 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   25.041267] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.764:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=871 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   25.041273] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.764:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=871 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   25.085622] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.808:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=873 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   25.085629] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.808:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper" pid=873 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   25.085632] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701195.808:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=873 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [   28.062159] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
    [   28.385352] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [   28.385355] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [   28.385358] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [   36.255858] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
    [   36.515107] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
    [   36.515146] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
    [   36.568587] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
    [   36.568941] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e0
    [   36.598438] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)
    [   36.598440] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00002001/00002000
    [   36.598442] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
    [   37.416115] audit_printk_skb: 42 callbacks suppressed
    [   37.416117] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701208.140:26): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1279/status" pid=1279 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=121 ouid=121
    [   37.416145] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701208.140:27): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=1279 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=121 ouid=0
    [   37.416184] audit: type=1400 audit(1507701208.140:28): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1279/status" pid=1279 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=121 ouid=121
    [   38.476394] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
    [   39.307158] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
    [   48.883007] wlp1s0: authenticate with 00:1e:a6:2a:0d:f8
    [   48.915598] wlp1s0: send auth to 00:1e:a6:2a:0d:f8 (try 1/3)
    [   48.920064] wlp1s0: authenticated
    [   48.922110] wlp1s0: associate with 00:1e:a6:2a:0d:f8 (try 1/3)
    [   48.926306] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 00:1e:a6:2a:0d:f8 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=37)
    [   48.927767] wlp1s0: associated
    [   48.927800] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
    [   50.144133] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
    [   55.770874] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    [   55.770883] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    [   55.770887] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
    [  299.861020] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

**Update: mcelog**

```
mcelog: failed to prefill DIMM database from DMI data
mcelog: Family 6 Model 8e CPU: only decoding architectural errors
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 0 BANK 6 
MISC 47880010086 ADDR fef1ff40 
TIME 1510722273 Wed Nov 15 10:34:33 2017
MCG status:
MCi status:
Error overflow
Uncorrected error
MCi_MISC register valid
MCi_ADDR register valid
Processor context corrupt
MCA: corrected filtering (some unreported errors in same region)
Generic CACHE Level-2 Generic Error
STATUS ee2000000040110a MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP c08 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0 
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 142
mcelog: Family 6 Model 8e CPU: only decoding architectural errors
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 1
CPU 0 BANK 7 
MISC 47880010086 ADDR fef1cec0 
TIME 1510722273 Wed Nov 15 10:34:33 2017
MCG status:
MCi status:
Error overflow
Uncorrected error
MCi_MISC register valid
MCi_ADDR register valid
Processor context corrupt
MCA: corrected filtering (some unreported errors in same region)
Generic CACHE Level-2 Generic Error
STATUS ee2000000040110a MCGSTATUS 0
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. The Realtek in your title is ethernet, not wireless. Your wireless is the Qualcomm Atheros. It clearly shows as connected and present in `nmcli`. Please edit your question to clarify the problem you are having.

Comment: What is meant by *not persistent*? Does it appear on some boots but not others? Does it connect sometimes but not others? Does it connect reliably but then disconnect? Or what?

Comment: @chili555 yes it reliably connects but within a few minutes it drops. Reinstated again and again drops. We have few more machines running ubuntu 14 and there it all works well, so it is not a network problem. It has to probably do with hardware and the wireless driver as far as my knowledge goes. It connects on every boot. Also sometimes the wifi icon is replaced by the wired connection icon of two arrows, even though the connection in use is wireless.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest that you turn off power saving in Network Manager. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Next, I read this post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=220809

> I solved the issue by deactivating the "WiFi Coexist" option in my
>   FritzBox router which apparently switches from 40MHz to 20MHz every
>   time it detects too many 40MHz routers nearby. This makes the ath10k
>   firmware crash (my old laptop and my phone handle those switches
>   nicely).

Accordingly, please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds.

Reboot the computer and the router and let us hear your report.

Comment: It yes WPA2-AES . I will try the rest and update soon. Thank you for the inputs.

Comment: I believe these 2 lines in the post you linked `[22692.952134] wlp2s0: AP 34:31:c4:77:9e:82 changed bandwidth, new config is 2447 MHz, width 2 (2437/0 MHz)
[22693.001133] ath10dk_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid b74d9d5b-7912-4f2b-961d-f559d884bc1f)` confirm that there is the frequency switch issue. I checked my dmesg(updated the question) but couldn't find any line related to this.

Comment: @chilli555 Hey I tried switching the frequency band to 20Mhz and still the problem stays. Also, after some more reading I installed `mcelog` and updated the question with the log. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: I see nothing in your `mcelog` relating to the wireless. It appears to be related to the CPU.